# How to tint a TextureRect?

Tags: c#, godot

Is there a way to tint a `TextureRect` in Godot 4.3? For example: Imagine a white icon on transparent background assigned to a `TextureRect`. Is there a way to draw the white icon in an arbitrary color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Inspector panel, Under Visibility, you will find the `modulate` and `self_modulate` properties. You can use them to tint (or change the opacity by tinting alpha) of any `CanvasItem` (including any `Control` and any `Node2D`).

The properties `modulate` and `self_modulate` differ in which item do they apply to. The property `modulate` applies to the item it is applied to and its children, while `self_modulate` only applies to the item but not to any of its children.

---

You may also, of course, create and set a custom `ShaderMaterial`. See [CanvasItem shaders](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shading/shading_reference/canvas_item_shader.html). With a fragment function, where you set whatever color you want.

For example, this shader will preserve alpha from the texture, but set everything red:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

void fragment()
{
    COLOR.a = texture(TEXTURE, UV).a;
    COLOR.rgb = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Or this other example will keep red and alpha (it multiplies red and alpha by 1, and green and blue by 0):

```
shader_type canvas_item;

void fragment()
{
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, UV) * vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

---

*And, yes, these combine. The effect of `modulate` and `self_modulate` is applied after the shader material.*